# Ember.js Masonry rendering doesn't wait for Data Models to be generated

Tags: ember.js, masonry

I am trying to build a masonry view of the top selling Items in a hypothetical eCommerce Site but Masonry is being rendered before the Data Models can be generated over RESTAdapter. Here are is my Ember.js code:

```
App.Userprofile = DS.Model.extend({
    loggedIn: DS.attr('boolean'),
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    totalItems: DS.attr('number'),
});

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

    setupController: function(controller) {
        this.store.find('userprofile', 'bat@man.com').then (function(userprofile) {
            controller.set ('model', userprofile);
        });
    }
});

App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.DjangoRESTAdapter.extend({
    host: HOST,
    namespace: 'api'
});

App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
    elementId: '',
    classNames: ['container','fullwidth'],
    templateName: 'application'
});

App.Cloud = DS.Model.extend({
    item: DS.attr('string'),
    numberItems: DS.attr('number'),
    rank: DS.attr('number')
});

App.CloudAdapter = DS.DjangoRESTAdapter.extend({
    host: HOST,
    namespace: 'api',
});

App.CloudController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ['application'],
    cloudSize: function() { // Determines the size of the div
        var cloudsize = Math.round (this.get('model.numberItems') * 5 / this.get('controllers.application.totalItems')) + 1;
        var divName = "score" + cloudsize.toString();
        return divName;
    }.property('model.numberItems', 'controllers.application.totalitems')
});

App.ItemcloudRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller) {
        this.store.findAll('cloud').then (function(itemcloud) {
            controller.set ('model', itemcloud);
        });
    }
});

App.ItemcloudController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    needs: ['cloud', 'application'],
    sortProperties: ['rank'],
});

App.ItemcloudView = Ember.View.extend({
    elementId: 'magicgrid',
    classNames: ['cloudcontainer'],
    templateName: 'itemcloud',
    didInsertElement: (function() {
        this._super();
        Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, this.applyMasonry);
    }).observes('controller.itemcloud'),

    applyMasonry: function() {
        setTimeout( function() { // settimeout to ensure masonry is called after data models are generate
            console.log ("applyMasonry being called");
            $('#magicgrid').masonry({
                itemSelector: '.company',
                isAnimated: true
            });
        }, 2000);
    }
});
```

Here is the portion of the template file where itemcloud is generated.

```
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name='itemcloud'>
            {{#each controller.model itemController="cloud"}}

                <div {{bind-attr class=":company cloudSize"}}>
                    <div class="companylogo">
                        <img src="images/logos/color-logos/logo-01.jpg" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="count">{{numberItems}}</div>
                </div>
            {{/each}}
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </script>
```

Now, I am struggling to find a way to hold the Masonry rendering until after the data is fetched due to the asynchronous nature of the data fetching and the template rendering. My research says that using a View for the CloudController Objects would be useful, but am trying to figure out if there is something I am missing in my current design. Also, if someone can provide pointers to use Views correctly here for the CloudController Objects

Let me know if I need to provide any more clarifications. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you doing it in the `setupController` Ember assumes the model is already ready and continues rendering the page despite the response not coming back from the server.

The easiest way to do it is to return your model/promise in the model hook.  Ember will wait on rendering the page until the model has been resolved.

```
App.ItemcloudRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){   
        this.store.find('cloud');
    }
});
```

The code above will do the same thing your code was doing, except Ember will wait for the find to resolve before creating and setting the model on the controller.

As per kingpin2k comments updating the answer to reflect the working code:

```
 App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {  
        return this.store.find ('userprofile', 'bat@man.com');  
    },  
    setupController: function(controller, model) {  
        controller.set ('model', model);  
    }  
});
```

Comment: Thanks kingpin2k, but I need itemCloudController to make sure that CloudController and ApplicationController are completed before that. CloudController in this case is dependent on a value fetched by ApplicationController (totalItems which is used to calculated the divSize in CloudController). How do I also handle this scenario?

Comment: Switch application route as well to use the model hook.  Child models won't be fetched until their parent resources have been resolved.

Comment: Super, thanks @kingpin2k - wonder how I missed that!! Setting the application route to use the model hook works perfectly fine. Have edited the answer to reflect this,